# Using both JDBCTemplate and JPA in spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate, spring-orm

I am working on a project in which Spring with JDBCTemplate is getting used. Now I want to migrate that project to JPA with Hibernate for database layer. So Situation is like to migrate some functionalities first and other later. 
1) Is It possible to have multiple templates for persistence?
2) What challenges may come as per your best knowledge?
3) Any other Suggestion, if any?

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) For sure. 2) To use JPA you will have to describe relations between different entities. 3) Too broad question, read JPA tutorials for details and examples

Comment: Any possibility of conflict between session or caching? @NikolayShevchenko